# База исходников

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте, где можно раздобыть базу исходников для С++ наподобие DelphiWorld?

Answer (score 1):

С++ С++'су разница. Если для Builder'a, то есть C++ World Professional 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

- [Исходники C++, Visual C++](http://www.cyberguru.ru/cpp-sources/)
- [Исходники по языкам программирования](http://ishodniki.ru/)
- [Исходники C++ Builder](http://sources.ru/builder/)

[**(!) И конечно же моя любимая база исходников**](http://tinyurl.com/3ufkoq7)

Answer (score 0):

От Microsoft: [All-In-One Code Framework](http://1code.codeplex.com/).